# Use InstancePerLifetimeScope or InstancePerDependency when registering for controllers and hosted services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm upgrading my project from classic ASP.Net to Asp.Net Core 3.1. In the old project I used to register my UoW and services like this:

```
builder.Register(x => new UnitOfWork())
    .As(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Now, in the new project I'm using hosted services which I call within a controller action. So I created a `BackgroundQueue` and `QueuedService` implementation and registering like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<BackgroundQueue>()
    .As<IBackgroundQueue>()
    .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<QueuedService>()
    .As<IHostedService>()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

A controller action might use one particular service. In such cases a lifetime scope is enough because instances are disposed of when the request ends. Now, a particular controller action will spawn a new queued service, such as:

```
backgroundQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct => { //Do stuff... });
```

The task might need to use an instance of the same particular service. In such a case, the task needs to create a completely new instance because the the task will keep on running long after the request has ended.

So, if I register the UoW and all my services always as `InstancePerDependency`, this should satisfy both cases?

Comment: `InstancePerLifetimeScope` is equivalent to `InstancePerWebRequest` in ASP.Net Core apps. I suppose your unit of work will be disposed after request ends. As long as your services do not use unit of work, it should be fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure an `IHostedService` is expected to be a singleton. I don't know Autofac but it looks like the registration is anything but. You may have issues with that from the framework side of things (the way the app is teared down, for example, stops all hosted services before the host itself)

Answer (score 2):

If the background job uses other services, for example `DbContext` which is registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope`, it may need to use a child scope with services registered for the scope of the job:

```
public class MyController
{
    public MyController(ILifetimeScope parentScope)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>()
            .WithParameters(new[] { new TypedParameter(typeof(DbContextOptions), MasterDbContext.GetOptions(masterDbConnectionString)) })
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
           .AsSelf();
        [..other services]

        var container = builder.Build();

        backgroundQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct => 
        { 
            using(container)
            {
                //Do stuff...
            } 
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: ILifetimeScope is for Autofac.  IServiceProvider is for dotnet core.  But it works almost the same way.

Comment: There’s no need to use a child scope which will pollute the controller code. Register as externally owned type can opt out automatic disposal. https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#disabling-disposal

Comment: Also, this can be dangerous as any service registered to the parent scope will be gone with the parent scope. If later try to resolve such service using the child scope, there will be an exception.

Comment: @weichch You are right in both points. Thank you. Modified the answer to fix the child scope.

Comment: @weichch Wouldn't it be a better solution to have the services injected into a constructor of some concrete class that's used as the background service?

Comment: @Ivan-Markdebono Yes, I guess this answer wants to show you how your scoped service could survive the auto disposal. In reality the lifetime management should not appear in controller.